# OpenRewrite: Add dependencies in Maven POM

Tags: openrewrite

I am trying to add a Spring cloud dependencies through OpenRewrite recipe:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

tried with `org.openrewrite.maven.AddDependency` , here version not required as it should come from bom or parent properties, but it is not working as below:-

```
- org.openrewrite.maven.AddDependency:
      groupId: io.awspring.cloud
      artifactId: spring-cloud-aws-starter
      releasesOnly: null
      optional: null
```

Comment: The version is required as per: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/maven/adddependency

Comment: @Tim Even after adding version also not reflecting change in rewrite.patch

- org.openrewrite.maven.AddDependency:
      groupId: io.awspring.cloud
      artifactId: spring-cloud-aws-starter
      version: 3.0.1

Comment: You'll also want to add a `onlyIfUsing` argument I suppose, based on what I see here: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/084fbd8b28e0724d68e837de6baa3d7d96445851/rewrite-maven/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/maven/AddDependency.java#L174

Comment: @Tim - onlyIfUsing argument is not much clear for me. 
`@Option(displayName = "Only if using",
            description = "Used to determine if the dependency will be added and in which scope it should be placed.",
            example = "org.junit.jupiter.api.*")
    String onlyIfUsing`

Is it only asking for scope ? how package name ex: org.junit.jupiter.api.* will be decided.
Please provide some more details.

Comment: Hi Manish; the `onlyIfUsing` argument should be a class that you're (already) using from the dependency that you're adding; it helps prevent adding a dependency to a project that's not used. There's some more examples here which could give you an idea of what to use: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aopenrewrite+onlyIfUsing+language%3AYAML&type=code&l=YAML